# Need Help Java Web App (webapp-runner, tomcat) heroku (app crashed)

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I have a Java web app on heroku. I created a web app that run webpage + server (apache jena fuseki) [using this tutorial from heroku webpage](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner). It works fine on localhost:3030 (execute batch file) and localhost:8080 using

```
java -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar target/*.war
```

I push it on heroku with Procfile like this

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

**The running app shows an Application Error when I tried to access it. Is there any way to resolve this?**

My heroku logs

```
[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[web.1]: May 07, 2017 7:27:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
[web.1]: SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.ShiroEnvironmentLoader
[web.1]: org.apache.jena.fuseki.FusekiConfigException: Failed to create directory: /etc/fuseki
[web.1]:    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiServer.ensureDir(FusekiServer.java:363)
[web.1]:    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiServer.formatBaseArea(FusekiServer.java:132)
[web.1]:    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.ShiroEnvironmentLoader.contextInitialized(ShiroEnvironmentLoader.java:50)
[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189)
[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[web.1]:
[web.1]: [2017-05-07 19:27:56] Server     ERROR Failed to initialize : Server not running
[web.1]: May 07, 2017 7:27:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
[web.1]: SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
[web.1]: May 07, 2017 7:27:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
[web.1]: SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
[web.1]: May 07, 2017 7:27:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
[web.1]: SEVERE: Context [] failed in [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] lifecycle. Allowing Tomcat to shutdown.
[web.1]: INFO: Cleaning up Shiro Environment
[web.1]: May 07, 2017 7:27:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
[web.1]: INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-55883]
[web.1]: May 07, 2017 7:27:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
[web.1]: INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-55883"]
heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=lmaokid.herokuapp.com request_id=3250ba55-3f3d-4bfd-a2e7-034c47f7b8d1 fwd="110.139.88.158" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3265ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=lmaokid.herokuapp.com request_id=90b84002-f43b-49f9-a88f-1e4df6a5e058 fwd="110.139.88.158" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

And my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>Maven Quick Start Archetype</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
    <artifactId>jena-fuseki</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
  </dependency>

   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
    <artifactId>jena-fuseki-war</artifactId>
    <type>war</type>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
  </dependency>

   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
    <artifactId>jena-fuseki-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
  </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                <version>8.5.11.3</version>
                                <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: Hi : I've the same problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305845/how-to-deploy-fuseki-war-on-heroku Did yon solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely, you'll see the main error:

```
Failed to create directory: /etc/fuseki
```

I recommend creating any directories under `/app` on Heroku, as this is the user space.